# Unity and Firebase Remote Config does not work on mobile ( Android )

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase-remote-config

So first, i  initialized the firebase ( because I also use the analytics service) [Firebase initiliaze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6VCv.png)
then fetch data( fetching is successful) but when i read the data it comes null when i run apk on mobile device. But it work on editor on my computer.
[Fetch and read data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAccJ.png)

[editor console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSuMx.png)

[on adroid , mobile device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seqDB.png)

so I would be glad if someone can help

I tried fetching stuff on firebase doc.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any logs from the Android and iOS devices? That might give us a clue--could be something related to the build setup. Often, everything will work fine in the editor, but something's missing from your builds for iOS and Android. A really common issue is that `google-services.json` and `GoogleService-Info.plist` are missing from the Android and iOS builds, so Firebase can't initialize.

Check out the [Debugging the Game Build, Install and Run Process guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/build-debug-guide#ensure_your_project_contains_and_is_using_valid_configuration_files) for a good troubleshooting primer that walks through the most common culprits.